# What is the proper way to update values of two Behavior Relays when one is subscribed to other?

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I have two BehaviorRelay-s, one is binded to second one. What is the proper way to update values of both inside one function?
For example:

```
class SetupProfileVM {
   let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
   let name= BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: nil)
   let username = BehaviorRelay<String?>(value: nil)

   name.bind(to: username).dispose(by: disposeBag)

   func setNewValues(name: String, username: String) {
       name.accept(name)
       username.accept(username)
   }
}
```

In this case i want username to be same as user when value is updated by textfield. But i also need this function to set new values to both name & username. What is the proper way of doing that? Can i be sure that username will be updated firstly by it's binding and only after that by it's new value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you even want to use BahaviorRelays here. For the behavior you are describing, I would expect to see something like this:

```
struct SetupProfileInputs {
    let nameField: Observable<String>
    let newValues: Observable<(name: String, username: String)>
}

struct SetupProfileVM {

    let name: Observable<String>
    let username: Observable<String>

    init(_ inputs: SetupProfileInputs) {
        name = Observable.merge(inputs.nameField, inputs.newValues.map { $0.name })
        username = Observable.merge(inputs.nameField, inputs.newValues.map { $0.username })
    }
}
```

Or possibly this (depending on what style of view model you are using.)

```
struct SetupProfileVM {

    struct Inputs {
        let nameField: Observable<String>
        let newValues: Observable<(name: String, username: String)>
    }

    struct Outputs {
        let name: Observable<String>
        let username: Observable<String>
    }

    func transform(_ inputs: Inputs) -> Outputs {
        let name = Observable.merge(inputs.nameField, inputs.newValues.map { $0.name })
        let username = Observable.merge(inputs.nameField, inputs.newValues.map { $0.username })
        return Outputs(name: name, username: username)
    }
}
```

In either case, you attach the text field to the `nameField` input. Whatever was calling the `SetupProfileVM.setNewValues(name:username:)` method needs to be converted to an Observable and connected to the `newValues` input.

Once you do that, every time the text field is updated, both `SetupProfileVM.name` and `SetupProfileVM.username` will emit the same value. Every time the newValues Observable emits a value, name and username will emit different values.